# Display index of 2 dimensional string array as their value.eg. arr[2][1] = "21" and arr[3][1] = "31" and so on

Tags: string, multidimensional-array

Basically I want to create a 2 dimensional string array char* grid[4][4], and want to display their index as their value. eg grid[2][1] will have string "21" as its value.
But their is some bug in this code, at run time it give me segmentation fault error. Please help me out.

`char* grid[DIMENSION][DIMENSION];`

```
for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++)
    {   
        char* c = malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
        c = "00\0";            
        c[0] = c[0] + i;
        c[1] = c[1] + j;
        grid[i][j] = c;

    }
}        

for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\t", grid[i][j]);         
    }

    printf("\n");
```

}

```
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
 char* c = "00";
 c[0] = c[0] + i;
```

with

```
char c[] = "00";
c[0] = c[0] + i;
```

it is not usually possible to change the value of a string literal.  With `gcc`, you can change this behavior by specifying `-fwritable-strings`.  Many compilers will put the string literal into a non-writable segment, but by declaring `c` as a character array it is guaranteed to be writable.  (Although, now you have issues with the assignment to `grid`, so you probably want to use `malloc`.)

```
char *c = xmalloc(3);  /* xmalloc wraps malloc with error checking */
c[0] = '0' + i;
c[1] = '0' + j;
c[2] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`char * c` exists inside the scope of the `for(int j...` loop , not outside it!

```
char * c = malloc(3);
strcpy(c,'00')
```